# iPhone X App Store Previews not working with iMovie?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, screenshot, iphone-x

I'm trying to submit a video preview for the App Store for my iPhone X app, but when I exported with iMovie, it's exporting in the iPhone 6 size, not X. When I tried uploading to iTunes Connect, it said it's the wrong size. I don't know if iMovie doesn't support the X yet or if it's a bug?

And is there any way for me to change the frame size of the video so I can upload? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately iMovie doesn't support iPhone X yet.
What you can try is changing the dimensions of exported video yourself as:

```
 ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 -strict -2 -vf scale=1080:1920 -ac 2 output_file.mp4
```

However video will be distorted. Another option is to use another editing software like Adobe Premier Pro.

**Edit:** For a free solution try [openshot](http://www.openshot.org/). It lets you export your video at custom dimensions. (Then you might have to run the command above)